# Error: model.get is not a function - emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I want to redirect my contacts page to contacts.show page so that while loading contacts page itself will display the first contact details.

But while loading contact page is got following error.

Error while processing route: contacts.index model.get is not a function TypeError: model.get is not a function

TypeError: model.get is not a function

contact.js

```
const { RSVP, $ } = Ember;
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
model() {
    return $.getJSON('/api/contacts')
},
redirect(model, transition) {
    this.transitionTo('contacts.show',model.get('firstObject'));
}
});
```

Can anyone help me? Please

Comment: try: `Ember.get(model, 'firstObject')`. Since you return a json object from your model, it is not an ember object.

Comment: Error while processing route: contacts.show You must provide param `contacts_id` to `generate`. Error: You must provide param `contacts_id` to `generate`. I tried but result is error :(

Comment: `Ember.get(model, 'firstObject')` retruns unidentifed which means null

Comment: what is your model parameter in that function? can you put `console.log(model);`

Comment: `console.log(model);` return [object Object]

Comment: `const {  $ } = Ember;                                                                                  import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
       return $.getJSON('/api/contacts')
    },
   redirect(model) {
       this.transitionTo('contacts.show',model.data[0]);
   }
}); `
This code works fine

Comment: @rajkeviv so `model.data` is your model. in that this should work `this.transitionTo('contacts.show',Ember.get(model.data, 'firstObject'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the same thing in setupController hook. And try first check is there any value before doing transition.

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);

    if (model.get('length') === 1) {
      this.transitionTo('contacts.show', model.get('firstObject'));
    }
}
```